# Необработанное исключение по адресу C++

Tags: c++

На 66-ой строчке выдаёт ошибку "необработанное исключение по адресу". Как фиксить?

В этой части -
`if ((n - 1) / j == 2) { isPalindrome = true; }`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");

    int a, b, n = 1, pow1, pow2, x, j = 0, reversed_a = 0, iteration = 0;
    bool isPalindrome = false;

    cout << "Программа получает на вход число. Если оно не является палиндромом, программа скаладывает его с перевернутой версией" << endl;
    cout << "числа до тех пор, пока число не станет палиндромом.\n" << endl;
    cout << "Введите число: ";
    cin >> a;       //Ввод числа

    while (isPalindrome == false) {
        b = a;      //Копия числа a

        while (b >= 10) {       //Подсчёт длины числа
            b = b / 10;
            n++;
        }

        int* arr;
        arr = new int[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {       //Создание массива, содержащего перевернутое число a по цифрам
            pow1 = (int)pow(10, i + 1);
            pow2 = (int)pow(10, i);
            x = (int)((a % pow1) / pow2);
            arr[i] = x;
        }

        int* new_arr;
        new_arr = new int[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {       //Переворот массива и получение числа a, записанное в массив по цифрам
            new_arr[i] = arr[n - (i + 1)];
        }

        /*/for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {        //Вывод массива на экран (для проверки правильности работы)
            cout << new_arr[i] << endl;
        }*/

        //Проверка числа a на палиндромность

        if (n % 2 == 0) {       //Если число состоит из чётного кол-ва цифр, проверяется, равняется ли первое число массива последнему, второе - предпоследнему и т.д.
            for (int i = 0; i < (n / 2); i++) {
                if (new_arr[i] == new_arr[n - (i + 1)]) {
                    j++;        //После каждого совпадения первого и последнего и т.д. чисел увеличивается переменная j
                }
            }

            if (n / j == 2) {       //Если число - палиндром, то количество совпадений будет равно половине от кол-ва всех цифр
                isPalindrome = true;
            }
        }
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < ((n - 1) / 2); i++) {       //Если число нечётное, то делается всё тоже самое, только без учёта числа по середине
                if (new_arr[i] == new_arr[n - (i + 1)]) {
                    j++;
                }
            }

            if ((n - 1) / j == 2) {     //Если число - палиндром, то количество совпадений будет равно половине от кол-ва всех цифр - 1
                isPalindrome = true;
            }
        }

        if (isPalindrome == false) {        //Преобразует массив из перевернутого числа а в перевернутое число а в типе int
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                reversed_a += (int)(arr[i] * pow(10, n - (i + 1)));
            }
            cout << a << " + " << reversed_a << " = " << a + reversed_a << endl;
            a += reversed_a;
        }

        iteration++;
    }

    cout << "Число a стало палиндромом спустя " << iteration << " итераций и сейчас равно " << a << endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В строке `if ((n - 1) / j == 2)` вы делите число `n - 1` на **результат сравнения** `j==2`. Если `j==2` будет `false` (т.е. число в переменной j не равно двум), то вы делите на ноль, что вызывает необработанное исключение.

Comment: Приоритет оператора `/` выше приоритета оператора `==`, поэтому в выражении `(n - 1) / j == 2` результат деления `(n - 1) / j` сравнивается со значением `2`.